# Problems with verification of SSL via Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Help to understand what is going on with my terraform module
In general it's working, it creates the SSL certificate and Route53 record correctly
But Failing on verification step no idea why, because the record is created successfully, but still getting an error that record not found :

> aws_acm_certificate_validation.this:
> Creating... ╷ │ Error: 1 error
> occurred: │   * missing course.com DNS validation record:
> _7eaea1fef0f356222c22a6bc1eb7bbd7.course.com

```
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "this" {
  domain_name       = var.domain
  validation_method = var.validation_method

  tags = {
    Name = var.domain,
    Environment = var.environment
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "this" {
  certificate_arn         = aws_acm_certificate.this.arn
  validation_record_fqdns = var.fqdn_records[*]
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "this" {
  for_each = {
    for dvo in aws_acm_certificate.this.domain_validation_options : dvo.domain_name => {
      name    = dvo.resource_record_name
      record  = dvo.resource_record_value
      type    = dvo.resource_record_type
      zone_id = var.zone_id
    }
  }

  allow_overwrite = true
  name            = each.value.name
  records         = [each.value.record]
  ttl             = 300
  type            = each.value.type
  zone_id         = each.value.zone_id
}
```

P.S. Not sure, but maybe problem that it's trying to find the dns record on my region (using eu-central-1) but still how to correct fix it no idea

Answer (score 0):

Can you try :

```
resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "cert_validation" {
  certificate_arn         = aws_acm_certificate.this.arn
  validation_record_fqdns = [for record in aws_route53_record.this : record.fqdn]
}
```